# NoSuchElementException on all elements on page with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

**Set-up**

I'm trying to log in to a [website](https://secure2.e-boekhouden.nl/bh/) using Python + Selenium.

My code to load the website is,

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path='/mypath/to/geckodriver')

url = 'https://secure6.e-boekhouden.nl/bh/'
browser.get(url)
```

---

**Problem**

Selenium cannot locate the element containing the account and password fields.

For example, for the field 'Gebruikersnaam',

```
browser.find_element_by_id('txtEmail')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="txtEmail"]')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('INPUTBOX')
```

all give `NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element`.

Even worse, Selenium cannot find the body element on the page,

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
```

gives `NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: /html/body`.

---

I'm guessing something on the page is either blocking Selenium (maybe the `'secure6'` in the url) or is written in a language/form Selenium cannot handle.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements are inside the frame. So that, it is throwing No Such Element exception. Please try to switch to the frame before all actions as given below.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path='/mypath/to/geckodriver')

url = 'https://secure6.e-boekhouden.nl/bh/'
browser.get(url)

browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id("mainframe"))

browser.find_element_by_id('txtEmail')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="txtEmail"]')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('INPUTBOX')
```